# Assigned variable at next VC is nil

Tags: swift

VC 1:

```
func onSelectOption(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let vc2 = VC2()
    vc2.selectedValue = "1"

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
}
```

VC 2:

```
var selectedValue: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(selectedValue) //prints nil
}
```

Anyone can explain why `selectedValue` is nil at VC2?

Comment: i guess this should work do you create `VC2` in IB ?

Comment: Each VC 1 and VC 2 has their own xib file..

Comment: It seems you view has been loaded before `selectedValue` has been set. That means you are probably loading `view` from your initializer which is questionable in the first place.

Comment: Did you override the init to initialize it with its xib? Because its not the case, but you still `selectedValue` shouldn't be nil. Is it really a String that you are passing? Not `vc2.myIBOutlet.text = "1"`?

Comment: @Rendy you need to load it correctly from xib , your current code assumes it's created programmatically

Comment: I do not override the init and do not have custom init, and I don't think make it to be loaded form xib solves the issue too

Comment: @Larme it is a custom object actually

Comment: Don't think , try it first and see ?

Comment: on `viewDidAppear()`, is the value still nil?

Comment: @Larme will `viewDidAppear` make a difference , if it's nil then it'll be there also

Comment: If you do `myVC = VC(); let _ = myVC.view; myVC.var = sth; present(myVC, animated: false)`, shouldn't `myVar` be `nil` on `viewDidLoad`, but not `viewDidAppear`. I'm wondering if there is no other override somewhere, custom stuff.

Comment: ok post a github link as your problem can't be reproduced if you need help

Comment: @Rendy Are you pushing VC2 from elsewhere?

Comment: Nope this VC2 only come from VC1. I have tried to load it by nib name also does not work :(

Comment: @Rendy I mean Do you push VC2 in multiple functions? For ex. 1. in onSelectOption method  and 2. from another button action

Answer (score 0):

try this (working only in storyboard):-

```
func onSelectOption(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifyerName") as! VC2
    vc2.selectedValue = "1"

    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
 }
```

Comment: i don't use storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom `initialiser` to `VC2` that accepts `selectedValue`.

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    @objc func onSelectOption(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let vc2 = VC2(selectedValue: "1")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    var selectedValue: String?

    init(selectedValue: String?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.selectedValue = selectedValue
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(selectedValue) //prints Optional("1")
    }
}
```

Since you are creating `VC2` without `storyboard`, `selectedValue` will not be set until after `viewDidLoad()` is called.

Comment: My VC1 created by `let vc1 = VC1ViewController(nibName: "VC1", bundle: nil);   let vc1NavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)` and I have tried use Button also does not work :(

Comment: By VC2 custom init method VC2's outlet connections will be nil

Comment: @RajeshKumarR What outlets? `VC2` is not created using `xib`. So that won't matter.

Comment: _"Each VC 1 and VC 2 has their own xib file"_ Check question's comments

Comment: Yes. But in the question VC2 is created independently without the xib file.

Comment: @PGDev yes. It is a mistake. He should fix that also